# Spring MVC not initial request mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Does the web deploy mechanism affect Spring MVC work?

I create a web project(SpringMVCTest) contains web.xml and a pjsp pages then I create a Java project(SpringMVCTestSrc) and use the link source function to link test_src and SpringMVCTestSrc.

My Eclipse workspace

[image]

My problem is if I deploy the project in war file then it works fine
, EX: if I open

> localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/message/showMessage.pages

it will forward to

> main/showMessage.jsp

**but** if I deploy the project with separate web and jar file it will no request mapping found like below.

```
[DEBUG]-[2015/07/30 15:03:39,o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet(init):139]: Servlet 'dispatcher' configured successfully
[DEBUG]-[2015/07/30 15:03:40,o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet(doService):861]: DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/SpringMVCTest/message/showMessage.pages]
[DEBUG]-[2015/07/30 15:03:40,o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping(getHandlerInternal):294]: Looking up handler method for path /message/showMessage.pages
[DEBUG]-[2015/07/30 15:03:40,o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping(getHandlerInternal):302]: Did not find handler method for [/message/showMessage.pages]
[WARN]-[2015/07/30 15:03:40,o.s.w.s.PageNotFound(noHandlerFound):1136]: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCTest/message/showMessage.pages] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

The log shows the different.

If I deploy in **war** file. The log shows found **18** bean definitions and request mapping works fine.

> 1. Export war file from Eclipse and put it to apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps
> 2. Startup Tomcat and open localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/message/showMessage.pages
> 3. The page will show Message : Hello world

```
o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(registerDefaultFilters):244]: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(doFindMatchingFileSystemResources):631]: Looking for matching resources in directory tree [D:\Temp\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest\WEB-INF\classes\in\hotkey\mvc]
o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(doRetrieveMatchingFiles):693]: Searching directory [D:\Temp\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest\WEB-INF\classes\in\hotkey\mvc] for files matching pattern [D:/Temp/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/SpringMVCTest/WEB-INF/classes/in/hotkey/mvc/**/*.class]
o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(findPathMatchingResources):424]: Resolved location pattern [classpath*:in/hotkey/mvc/**/*.class] to resources [file [D:\Temp\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest\WEB-INF\classes\in\hotkey\mvc\MainForm.class]]
o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(findCandidateComponents):286]: Identified candidate component class: file [D:\Temp\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest\WEB-INF\classes\in\hotkey\mvc\MainForm.class]
o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader(loadBeanDefinitions):224]: Loaded 18 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:test-dispatcher-context.xml]
```

If I deploy with **separate web and jar** file. The log shows found **17** bean definitions and request mapping does not work.

> 1. Build a directory in apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps, EX: apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest
> 2. Copy WEB-INF, META-INF from Eclipse workspace to apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest
> 3. Export jar file from SpringMVCTestSrc and put it to apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\SpringMVCTest\WEB-INF\lib
> 4. Startup Tomcat and open localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/message/showMessage.pages
> 5. The page shows HTTP 404

```
o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(registerDefaultFilters):244]: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(findPathMatchingResources):424]: Resolved location pattern [classpath*:in/hotkey/mvc/**/*.class] to resources []
o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader(loadBeanDefinitions):224]: Loaded 17 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:test-dispatcher-context.xml]
```

Does someone know why the same code but different deploy mechanism has different result?

My code as blow

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:test-service-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:test-dispatcher-context.xml</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.pages</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Spring Configuration(test-service-context.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="testMessageService" class="in.hotkey.service.TestMessageService" >
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Spring MVC Config(test-dispatcher-context.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">    


    <mvc:annotation-driven />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="in.hotkey.mvc"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>        

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />     
</beans>
```

Main Controller

```
package in.hotkey.mvc;

import in.hotkey.service.TestMessageService;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainForm {

    @RequestMapping(value="/message/showMessage.pages")
    public ModelAndView handleShowMessage() throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("main/showMessage");
        mv.addObject("message", "Hello world!");

        return mv;
    }   

}
```

JSP Content

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h4>Message : ${message}</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Does someone know what the problem is*: no. That's what you should tell us. How doesn't it work. What do you do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Precisely. With error messages and everything.

Comment: Sorry I`m the newbie here and it not allow me paste image or link. I just try to explain more with my poor English and add the system log. Thx your comment.

Comment: How do you mapping "/message/showMessage.pages".
@RequestMapping should either be mapped to form action or ajax URL.
Please share your jsp page, if you want more clarification on it.

Comment: I guess there's a mistake in the URI that you are mapping. Lose the extension. It should be,   `@RequestMapping(value="/message/showMessage")`

Comment: The jsp file is very simple it only show a message.

Comment: I know what is the structure of a war file, I also know what is jar. But I cannot imagine what means : *deploy the project with separate web and jar file*. You should describe what is that deployment procedure.

Comment: @Antonov, is it your first page?
If yes, then use @RequestMapping(value="/") rather than @RequestMapping(value="/message/showMessage.pages").

There is no need of defining "/message/showMessage.pages". Your viewResolver will automatically linked it to the ModalAndView.

Comment: I add some description for deploy. Hope it will explain this problem more detail.

Comment: I have try to change @RequestMapping(value="/")  and it seems not the problem.

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
  /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value></c-p>
Use this

Comment: Please refer the above web.xml entries, this one is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem is....

Root cause founded from [Spring MVC document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).
[image]

It means annotation scan need directory entries!!
The problem is if I export whole project into war file. It contains the complete directory entries in WEB-INF/classes directory but jar file has no directory entry information.

Resolve this problem just check the "Add directory entries" option in Eclipse export function.

[image]